# total number of evetns per users using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Having two time series: [a.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1njOL0AGJvnGq5nMBvDw374WYWvt_bKSX/view?usp=sharing) and [b.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZNyIvbTSdFw13rIty4ZIjN3z2SgS6h9D/view?usp=sharing), I'm having a hard time interpreting and generating: "Histogram of total number of events per users for all 30+ years old male users" (in Python using Pandas, matplotlib)

This is my work so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv("a.csv") ## 
df1 = pd.read_csv("b.csv") ##
event_date = df['event_date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
s1 = pd.merge(df, df1, how ='left', on=['user_id'])  ## merge casedf and demodf 
s2 = s1[['user_id', 'event_date', 'age', 'gender']].groupby(['user_id', 'event_date']).agg(['mean', 'count'])
counts = s1.groupby('user_id').size()
counts
d1f = counts.to_frame().reset_index()
d1f.head()
d1f = d1f.rename(columns={'user_id': 'USER-ID', 0: 'TOTAL-EVENTS'})
d1f.head() 
d2f = pd.read_csv("users.csv") 
# df2.head()
d2f = d2f.rename(columns={'age': 'AGE', 'gender': 'GENDER', 'user_id': 'USER-ID'})
d2f.head()
d1 = pd.merge(d1f, d2f, how ='left', on=['USER-ID'])  
d1.head()
d2m = d1[(d1["AGE"] > 30) & (d1["GENDER"] == 'm')]
d2m
x = d2m['TOTAL-EVENTS']
num_bins = 30
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

I think not only I'm interpreting the required histogram wrong but also over killing myself for producing/plotting it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, I think this question seems to be too broad. Where you are getting stuck? What is your expected result? limit your question to specific problem. So, that it will be easy to answer to others.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Thanks. My expected result is: "Histogram of total number of events per users for all 30+ years old male users". I'm not sure if I'm understanding it or plotting it correctly.

Comment: @KyleDickson, have a look at the answer I have posted. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

All looks good except this. for getting event count per user, you need to group the values.

From

```
x = d2m['TOTAL-EVENTS']
```

To

```
x = d2m['TOTAL-EVENTS'].groupby(['USER-ID'])
```

Comment: complains:  `... /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in _get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate)
   3289                 in_axis, name, level, gpr = False, None, gpr, None
   3290             else:
-> 3291                 raise KeyError(gpr)
   3292         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
   3293             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: 'USER-ID'`

Comment: python3: `Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
    x = d2m['TOTAL-EVENTS'].groupby(['USER-ID'])
  ...
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 3291, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'USER-ID'`

Comment: replace `USER-ID` by nthe actual name of your column

Comment: @RafaelC like, for example, 12? Then how could it be a histogram for all ages (30+)? I'm confused.

Comment: @KyleDickson, Can you show me the result for d1.head()

Answer (score 0):

There are too many lines of unnecessary commands in your code.

**Below code does what you need.**

(You might want to check the formatting options for the plot.)

```
events = pd.read_csv("C:/Test/timeseries_events.csv")
users = pd.read_csv("C:/Test/timeseries_users.csv")
# Merge both
s1 = pd.merge(events, users, how ='left', on=['user_id']) # merge events and users df
s2 = s1[(s1["age"] > 30) & (s1["gender"] == 'm')].reset_index() # filter required data based on your conditions
s2['event_count'] = s2.groupby('user_id')['event_date'].transform('count') # Adds new column for count of events
s2 = s2[['user_id','age','event_count']] # Keep only required columns so that unique rows can be selected in the next step.
s3 = s2.drop_duplicates()

# Plot histogram using pd.plot()
s3.hist(column=['age'], bins=8, align= 'mid', rwidth=0.8, range = (30,70))

[Out]: array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000000FD037F0>]],
      dtype=object)
```

[image]

I have managed to reach upto this plot (bin size = 5 so 7 bins from 30 to 70) but I feel that the count is not correct for each bin.

Comment: Giving me error: `s2.plot(x='user_id',y='count',kind='hist') ... File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
...
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'count' `

Comment: s2.head(): 
`index  user_id           event_date   age gender  event_count
0    657        2  2015-03-06 00:00:00  35.0      m          NaN
1    658        2  2015-03-19 00:00:00  35.0      m          NaN
2    659        2  2015-03-15 00:00:00  35.0      m        126.0
3    660        2  2015-02-27 00:00:00  35.0      m         65.0
4    661        2  2015-02-26 00:00:00  35.0      m          NaN`

Comment: Sorry, small typo. I had renamed 'count' to 'error_count' while posting. Should work now :)

Comment: Ah just caught it and was typing it. Thanks a lot for your terse code. Would you have any comment on interpreting the histogram itself (rather than coding). I believe it should have the total number of events in y-axis where the ages (or bins) are in x-axis. Am I right? Would you mind adding the code for the latter interpretation before I go accept the code, if you feel I'm right.

Comment: Great! We have selected user IDs on x-axis so starting from 0 to whatever's the upper limit. 
On y-axis, we have the count of events. 
It does not reflect ages, as it is now, but I guess there are options available to show that. You can read more about the pd.plot() options.
If you like the answer, don't forget to mark as accepted, thanks :)

Comment: Sure. But user-ids are just between `0-89` and `200-227`. Can you please check the input files. I'm not sure x axis is reflecting them in your plot.

Comment: Oh.. sorry if I missed that, let me check again.

Comment: I think since we are trying to group by 'user_id' it gives us count of all the entries of user_id. We need to groupby using the count of non-null event_date.

Will update the code.

Comment: X should show the bucket or bin of users aga30 (like30to350 and y direction showes the number event they attended in a in bin,

Comment: This is tougher than I expected. I have managed to give the plot a more user-friendly design and added the bins but the count is still not correct :(